# can anyone tell me how to read the contents of a file into the following structure in c

Tags: c, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read contents of a structure using fread() in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333074/how-to-read-contents-of-a-structure-using-fread-in-c)

I have to read the contents of a file created by a program based on the following structure. I tried to do it but it seems i got it messed up that, first i didn't get the right result and second when i post the code here on stackoverflow(you can go to my page and see it for yourself) the answers i got are not enough to solve my problem.
So can anyone tell me how to read the content of the file into the following structure?

```
struct test 
{ 
   uint64_t start; 
   uint16_t length; 
   struct test *next;    
};
```

Comment: Maybe you should also tell us what you are expecting as results in your structure...

Comment: What kind of content does the file contain? A series of start/length pairs?

Comment: @TimCooper: you are right it is the same question

Comment: @Macmade: I want to be able to read the content and display as well as use it as an input to another operation

Comment: @IceCoder: it contains these format of data,                    0,43  
43,95  
138,159 Each pair is on a new line

Comment: @John That doesn't make sense, until you provide more details... Voting to close, sorry.

Comment: @Macmade: please visit this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333074/how-to-read-contents-of-a-structure-using-fread-in-c)

Comment: @John If you already asked such a question, please don't post it twice. If you're question is somehow related to a question you asked before, please add links, and explain the context. We can't guess what you mean, and what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Wait, do you have a **text** file you're trying to read into a linked list?

Comment: Then you have a clue in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8333643/10077) to your original question. You'll have to read each line, parse it, create a new node for your list, and link it on the end of the list so far.

Comment: I just replied an ans to your other questions. Hope that will solve your query.

Answer (score 0):

This is the test code I've just written, and works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILE_NAME "./test.dat"

#define uint64_t unsigned long long
#define uint16_t unsigned short int

struct test
{
  uint64_t start;
  uint16_t length;
  struct test* next;
};

int main()
{
 FILE *f = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
 struct test *t, *first, *tp;
 t = first = (struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
 while(!feof(f))
 {
  char a[16];
  char *at;

  fgets(a, 16, f);
  if(a[strlen(a)-1] != '\n')
   break;
  at = (char*)strtok(a, ",");
  t->start = (uint64_t)strtoull(at, 0, 10);
  at = strtok(0, ",");
  if(at)
  t->length = (uint16_t)strtoul(at, 0, 10);
  t->next = (struct test*)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
  tp = t;
  t = t->next;
 }
 free(t);
 tp->next = 0;
 fclose(f);

 t = first;
 while(t != 0)
 {
  printf("%llu %hu\n", t->start, t->length);
  struct test *k = t;
  t = t->next;
  free(k);
 }

}
```

It reads the data from a file called "test.dat" (as you can see). Here is the test file I used:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
9,7
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you!